# Where is prisma cli installed in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, prisma

After I read prisma [article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-cli/installation),I can execute `npm install prisma --save-dev` and `npx prisma`. After that,
I searched where `prisma` cli was installed.
multiple cli has symbolic link from `node_modules/.bin`  to its actual file,so I search`prisma`in this directory but it couldn't be found. where is `prisma cli` installed ?

```
~/test/src/test% ls -ltr node_modules/.bin 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 17 Jan 28 03:08 ts-jest -> ../ts-jest/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 27 Jan 28 03:08 prettier -> ../prettier/bin-prettier.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 15 Jan 28 03:08 lerna -> ../lerna/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 21 Feb  1 04:42 npx -> ../npm/bin/npx-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 45 Feb  1 04:42 npm-install-peers -> ../npm-install-peers/bin/npm-install-peers.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 21 Feb  1 04:42 npm -> ../npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 26 Feb  1 09:06 tsserver -> ../typescript/bin/tsserver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hikarmiy amazon 21 Feb  1 09:06 tsc -> ../typescript/bin/tsc
```

Thanks

Comment: I see symlinks for `prisma` and `prisma2` in `node_modules/.bin` after installing `prisma`. The binaries are defined [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/3.10.0/packages/cli/package.json#L63)

Comment: I could install `prisma`,and execute them.. but I couldn't find symlink in `node_modules/.bin` so I would misunderstand something.. Thanks